# MDI Form Blinking when loading

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2010 to create a project
in the main menu form other form are loaded as MDI child form 
child forms being none border style yet it blinks a border when loading and looks unprofessional.

```
studentForm obj = new studentForm();
obj.MdiParent = this;
obj.Show();
```

Please Help

Comment: MDI child windows **must** have a border. Winforms forgets to throw an exception.

Comment: @HansPassant Isn't there any way to overcome this ?

Comment: @HansPassant any alternatives to connect one form within the other Form than MDI ?

Comment: What you are looking for is an ordinary UserControl.

Comment: try setting the form's DoubleBuffer property to true, see i fthat helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of blinking. I was setting the form border to none through a master class programmatically. But then I rather than doing that I set the border to None through the property box itself and than voila !! blinking  stopped.

Try it you might get around your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```